# Nested UINavigationController Flow corrupted

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have problem with NavigationController..My flow of navigation controller to create stack goes like

**case 1:-**`A--->B--->C`
**case 2:-** `D--->B--->C`

This is actual flow to call navigationController where A,B,C,D are the different stacks.
I call these stacks by this method:

```
B *b=[[B alloc]init]
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:b animated:YES];
```

**Problem** 
when I move in order `A-->B-->C` and then navigates back `C-->B-->A`
this works fines ..now when again if i moves to `D-->B` but  it takes me to the `C`

and 
**error**`nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation`
why this error is coming ??

Note..`A and D` are on the same stack.

Comment: Share code when you again if you moves to D-->B...

Comment: same one which i used above(edited) ...check I have corrected in moving   A-->B  ..

Comment: @Vishal can you tell me ..wen we navigate back..which method is been called?? ViewDidLoad I dont think will be called

Comment: ViewWillAppear method dude...

Answer (score 1):

Try this... Hope it will help you...

```
 NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[ viewContrlls count];i++)
{
    id obj=[viewContrlls objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[Yourclassname class]])
    {

        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}

Yourclassname is your class which you want to push or pop and nothing to change
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this whenever you push a VC

```
YourAppDelegate *delegate=(YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.window.navigationController pushViewController:whateverVCYouWant];
```

This will have only one navigation stack, so all your push and pop happens in a single stack.